Setting up a Second Clock with Different Timezone in Emacs Mode-line
I am trying to set up a second clock with a different timezone in the
Emacs mode-line using the following code, but it doesn't seem to have
any effect:
(setq-default mode-line-format
              (list
               ;; Set up the time and date
               '(:eval
                 (when (mode-line-window-selected-p)
                   (propertize
                    (format-time-string
                     " W%W/d%j %-m/%-d(%a) %H:%M " (current-time))
                    'face 'shadow)))
               'default-directory
               '(:eval
                 (propertize
                  (format-time-string
                   " B%H " (current-time) "Europe/Berlin")
                  'face 'shadow))))

Any hints?

The Berlin time should be appearing. When I ran this code (with no init file) my modeline read
W18/d124 5/3(Fri) 00:47 ~/ B06. This "B06" is a "B" concatenated with the hour in Berlin.
You should note that if you set the modeline this way, this same modeline will appear exactly the same for every buffer unless mode-line-format is manually set for each buffer. Rather than set this value directly, you could instead prepend or append these times to each buffer's mode-line-format, but I'm not familiar enough with the modeline to know the best way to accomplish this.
